# Is there a way to check if stunnel is running from javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, stunnel

I would like to check that stunnel is running and was wondering if there was some way to figure that out from a chrome extension.

Comment: In JavaScript running in what? In a web-page? In a Chrome extension (implied from your tags)? In node.js?

Comment: Chrome extension. I didn't realize it was unclear since it was tagged.

Comment: Do you want to check if it runs on your local machine where your chrome runs, or on the server you are connecting to using chrome?

Comment: @StefanHegny local machine (chrome extension checking if stunnel is running locally). Chrome has some mixed content limitations so I found the easiest way to get comply with them is to access my database via stunnel since the database has some bugs related to SSL (so I run the database as http)

Answer (score 0):

On Linux Redhat (possibly many other distros), it is possible to check whether stunnel is running by executing the following command as root,

```
ps aux | fgrep stunnel
```

In whichever medium you're executing your JavaScript code (Node / Chrome Extension / etcetera..) try executing this bash command.

Comment: BTW: This question is a bit unclear. It, probably, would have been a better idea to wait to answer this question until the OP adds a bit more clarity to the question. As it is, the question isn't clear how they are running their JavaScript. However, given that they have not included a node.js tag, it's unlikely that Node is the environment in which they are wanting to run. Given their tags, the most likely thing is that they are intending to run some JavaScript in a Chrome extension, but it really could be anything.